# React State Update Issue: New Posts Overwriting Existing Posts in Social Media Feed Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, render

I'm working on a React social media feed component, but I'm encountering a strange issue. When I add a new post to the feed, the first one looks fine, but the other, nstead of getting their own values, they getting the values from the first post added.

Here's the relevant part of my Feed component:

```
import PostBox from '../PostBox/PostBox';
import Posts from '../Post/Posts';
import PostsResult from '../PostsResult/PostsResult';
import PostList from '../Post/PostsList';

const Feed = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState(PostList);
    const [isUpdated, setIsUpdated] = useState(false);

    const addPost = (postContent) => {
        const newPost = {
            username: "username", 
            timestamp: "Just now",
            content: postContent,
            likes: 0,
            comments: [],
            image: ""
        };
        
        setIsUpdated(true);
        setPosts([newPost, ...posts,]);  
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <PostBox addPost={addPost} />
            {isUpdated ? <PostsResult posts={posts} /> : <Posts posts={posts} />}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Feed;
```

And here's the PostsResult component:

```
import React from 'react';
import CreatePost from '../Post/CreatePost';

function PostsResult({ posts }) {
    const renderedPosts = posts.map((post) => (
        <CreatePost {...post} />
    ));

    console.log("Posts in PostsResult", posts);
    
    return (
        <div>
            {renderedPosts}
        </div>
    );
}

export default PostsResult;
```

I checked on the console and `posts`really getting the right value, but still on page i can't see it well.

I've checked for direct mutations to the posts array and ensured that the state updates are not asynchronous issues. The PostList is a static array that serves as the initial state.

Could anyone suggest why the existing posts are being overwritten and how to resolve this issue?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Post.css';

const CreatePost = ({ id, username, timestamp, originalContent, likes, comments, image }) => {
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved, setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [editableContent, setEditableContent] = useState(originalContent);

  const Remove = () => {
    setIsRemoved(true);
  };

  const handleLike = () => {
    setIsLiked(!isLiked);
  };

  const handleEdit = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    setIsEditing(false);
    // Here you would typically update the post content in your backend
    // For now, we're just updating the local state
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setEditableContent(event.target.value);
  };

  if (isRemoved) {
    return null;
  }


  return (
    isRemoved ? null :
      <div className="post">
        <div className="post-header">
          <div className="post-header-info">
            <p className="username">{username}</p>
            <p className="timestamp">{timestamp}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="post-header-actions">
            {isEditing ? (
              <button onClick={handleSave}>Save</button>
            ) : (
              <i className="bi bi-pencil-square Edit" onClick={handleEdit}></i>
            )}
            <button className="x-button" onClick={Remove}><i className="bi bi-x-lg"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="post-content">
          {isEditing ? (
            <textarea value={editableContent} onChange={handleChange} className="edit-textarea" />
          ) : (
            <p>{editableContent}</p>
          )}
          {image && <img src={image} alt="Post Image" className="post-image" />}
        </div>

        <div className="buttons">
          <button className="like-button" onClick={handleLike}>
            <i className="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up"></i>
            &nbsp; Likes: {isLiked ? likes + 1 : likes}
          </button>

          <button className="comment-button">
            <i className="bi bi-chat"></i>
            &nbsp; Comments: {comments.length}
          </button>

          <button className="share-button">
            <i className="bi bi-send"></i>
            &nbsp; Share
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};

export default CreatePost;
```

Comment: Would you be able to update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: can you show the CreatePost componenent

Comment: try adding  a unique `key` to the posts so that it is used in your `map` of the `CreatePost`.

Comment: @DuckDuckGoose added in the end of the query

Answer (score 0):

did you try writing `setPosts([...posts, newPost]);`  instead of `setPosts([newPost, ...posts]);` at the feed component and don"t forget to add key prop to CreatePost component while mapping `<CreatePost  key={"post id here"} {...post} />`